# Tools bar missing from rviz on Mac OS X

Tags: rviz, macos, osx, macos-lion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I've just noticed that my rviz is not showing the Tools bar, this is the bar on the top that has buttons for moving the camera, selecting, setting goals, etc.

I installed ros electric using the homebrew tutorial. My Mac OS X version is 10.7.3. Rviz compiled just fine, though I do get some warnings at the rviz startup.

Does anyone else have this problem? Any ideas on how to get the Tools bar?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31203/tools-bar-missing-from-rviz-on-mac-os-x/) by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 591 on 2012-04-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not really an answer, more of an alternative, I still cannot see the Toolbar with the buttons on my rviz on Mac OS X, however I did find out that the keyboard shortcuts work!!!

So if I want to set a goal I can just press g on the keyboard, if I want to set the robot pose I can press p, etc...

---

Originally posted by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) with karma: 591 on 2012-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1